# List all files that are not ignored by .gitignore

Tags: git, list, file

I would like to list all files that are not ignored by .gitignore, ie all source files of my repository.

`ag` does it well by default, but I'm not aware of an approach that works without installing additional software.

`git ls-files` without options works almost well but doesn't take into account the files that have been modified/created, for example if I create a new file bar without commiting it, `git ls-files` doesn't show that file.

Comment: did you mean `ag -l`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
git status --short| grep  '^?' | cut -d\  -f2-
```

will give you untracked files.

If you union it with `git ls-files`, you've got all unignored files:

```
( git status --short| grep '^?' | cut -d\  -f2- && git ls-files ) | sort -u
```

you can then filter by

```
( xargs -d '\n' -- stat -c%n 2>/dev/null  ||: )
```

to get only the files that are stat-able (== on disk).

Comment: What is the `||:` part ??

Comment: `: == true`; to ignore the nonzero exit status of `stat`, which is to be expected unless all the files on stdin really do exist on disk

Comment: (`2>/dev/null and ||:` potentially hides other failures in `stat` such as EPERM, ENOMEM, or EIO fails, but you shouldn't get any of those unless your repo and your system are in a very weird state, in which case you'd be getting lots of errors from other utilities)

Comment: p.s. It seems that `git status --short` will give **directory** name if a new directory and some files under it is added, instead of *directory + file* name.

Comment: how would you chain the `xargs` part with the rest? or store the results in an array?

Comment: @yoannisj Using `|`, i.e., `( git status --short| grep '^?' | cut -d\  -f2- && git ls-files ) | sort -u | ( xargs -d '\n' -- stat -c%n 2>/dev/null  ||: )`

Comment: @PSkocik oh ok, I see. The parenthesis around the `xargs -d ...` command threw me off there. This is working very well, thanks!

I also managed to store the results in an array by using command substitution:

`project_files=$(( git status --short | grep '^?' | cut -d\  -f2- && git ls-files ) | sort -u | ( xargs -d '\n' -- stat -c%n 2>/dev/null  ||: ))`

Comment: From the documentation, it seems `git ls-files -c -m -o` should do the trick. Or am I mistaken ?

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way, using `git check-ignore` which you may find it cleaner:

```
find . -type f
```

will give you all the files in the current folder.

```
find . -type f -not -path './.git/*'
```

will give you all the files, with the exception of everything in .git folder, which you definitely don't want to include. then,

```
for f in $(find . -type f -not -path './.git/*'); do echo $f; done
```

is the same as above. Just a preparation to the next step, which introduce the condition. The idea is to use the `git check-ignore -q` which returns exit 0 when a path is ignored. Hence, here is the full command

```
for f in $(find . -type f -a -not -path './.git/*'); do
    if ! $(git check-ignore -q $f); then echo $f; fi
done
```

Comment: Nice! Just note that this is very slow if you have large directories that are ignored, e.g. `node_modules`. You have to keep adding the large directories, which somewhat defeats the purpose of trying to automatically respect the `.gitignore` file. But just adding `-not -path './node_modules/*'` is good enough for my use.

Comment: This one-liner is much faster since it avoids repeat calls to `git check-ignore`. It also uses `-prune` which should be more efficient: `find . -name '.git' -prune -or -type f -print | git check-ignore --verbose --non-matching --stdin | sed -n 's/^::\t//p'`

Answer (score 4):

`git ls-files --cached --others --exclude-standard` will give you the info you want.

- `--cached` -- Show files that git knows about. (Plain `git ls-files` with no options is equivalent to passing this option.)
- `--others` -- Show files that git *doesn't* know about. This includes ignored files by default, but...
- `--exclude-standard` -- Don't include ignored files in the output.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd).

The command to run is:

```
fd -H
```

Please note that in case there is no `.git` directory and only a `.gitignore` file (ex. bare repo), you have to specifically tell where the .gitignore file is.

```
fd -H --ignore-file .gitignore
```

For more details please check [here](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd/issues/1032#issuecomment-1148439224).

Comment: very good, I have been seeking this solution about 3 days! I used rsync dry-run before, but it just ignores some .gitignore expressions

Answer (score 0):

Shorter variant of [Uri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59888964):

- to find ignored files:

```
find . -not -path ./.git/\* -type f -exec git check-ignore -q {} \; -print
```

- to find non-ignored files:

```
find . -not -path ./.git/\* -type f -not -exec git check-ignore -q {} \; -print
```